# All routes for a single controller returning 404 error

Tags: php, laravel

Every routes on the project works fine except my TicketController's routes. The routes worked fine but suddenly stop working. So far i've tried php artisan route:clear, php artisan cache:clear and php artisan config:clear. I have also ensured that there wasn't any duplicate in my web.php

```
 // Tickets
Route::resource('/tickets', 'TicketController',['except' => ['show','store','destroy']]);
Route::delete('tickets/delete', 'TicketController@destroy')->name('tickets.destroy');
Route::delete('tickets/destroy', 'TicketController@multiDestroy')->name('tickets.massDestroy');
Route::post('tickets/store/{ticket}', 'TicketController@store')->name('tickets.store');
Route::post('tickets/media', 'TicketController@storeMedia')->name('tickets.storeMedia');
Route::post('tickets/comment/{ticket}', 'TicketController@storeComment')->name('tickets.storeComment');
Route::get('tickets/view/{ticket}','TicketController@show')->name('tickets.show');
Route::get('/search','TicketController@search')->name('search');
```

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dRu2.png)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code. Code is text, copy and paste it into your question.

Comment: Also post the error you are getting while hitting these routes

Comment: can you show your error message trace?

Comment: @sohailamar i just posted the error

Answer (score 1):

In your web.php, Ticket's Resource route is conflicting with other Ticket's Routes. Just change the placement of Resource Route from top to bottom. Use this code:

```
Route::delete('tickets/delete', 'TicketController@destroy')->name('tickets.destroy');
Route::delete('tickets/destroy', 'TicketController@multidestroy')->name('tickets.massDestroy');
Route::post('tickets/store/{ticket}', 'TicketController@store')->name('tickets.store'); 
Route::post('tickets/media', 'TicketController@storeMedia')->name('tickets.storeMedia');
Route::post('tickets/comment/{ticket}', 'TicketController@storeComment')->name('tickets.storeComment');
Route::get('tickets/view/{ticket}', 'TicketController@show')->name('tickets.show');
Route::get('/search', 'TicketControllergsearch')->name('search');

Route::resource('/tickets', 'TicketController', ['except' => ['show', 'store', 'destroy']]);
```

Comment: i tried this but it still showed the same error

Comment: Try clearing your routes cache after @Romantic Dev solution